# Error: Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting this error: Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

I searched on internet, but i don't know how to apply the correction in my case. I found different types of query only.

I'm trying to get a Count result in a field (line 5), but when I add the Count query i'm getting this error.

I'm using SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

When I remove the Count from SELECT and GROUP BY the query run correctly.

```
SELECT TF.COD_FORNECEDOR AS 'Cód. Fornec.',
    TF.NOM_FANTASIA AS 'Fornecedor',
    DM.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO AS 'CONTRATO',
    UA2.NOM_USUARIO AS 'NOM_USUARIO_COMPRADOR',
    (SELECT COUNT(COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO) FROM TB_DEMANDA D INNER JOIN TB_PROCESSO P ON D.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO = P.NUM_CONTRATO WHERE D.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO = DM.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO) AS 'NUM_ADITIVO',
    0 AS 'Qtd. Aditivo',
    SUM(DM.VAL_TOTAL_ORCADO) AS 'Valor Inicial',
    SUM(TP.VAL_CONTRATADO) AS 'Valor Final',
    ((SUM(TP.VAL_CONTRATADO) / SUM(DM.VAL_TOTAL_ORCADO)) -1) * 100 AS 'Var. %'
FROM TB_FORNECEDOR TF 
    LEFT JOIN TB_DEMANDA DM ON DM.COD_FORNECEDOR = TF.COD_FORNECEDOR
    LEFT JOIN TB_PROCESSO TP ON DM.COD_DEMANDA = TP.COD_DEMANDA
    LEFT JOIN TB_PROCESSO_FORNECEDOR PF ON PF.COD_PROCESSO = TP.COD_PROCESSO
    LEFT JOIN USUARIO UA ON UA.NUM_USUARIO = DM.NUM_USUARIO_COMPRADOR
    LEFT JOIN USUARIO UA2 ON UA2.NUM_USUARIO = DM.NUM_USUARIO_COMPRADOR
    LEFT JOIN TB_STATUS_DEMANDA_DATA SD ON SD.COD_DEMANDA = DM.COD_DEMANDA
    LEFT JOIN TB_BASELINE BA ON BA.COD_PROCESSO = TP.COD_PROCESSO
    LEFT JOIN TB_BASELINE_TAREFAS BT ON BT.COD_BASELINE = BA.COD_BASELINE AND BT.COD_PROCESSO = BA.COD_PROCESSO
    LEFT JOIN TB_STATUS_PROCESSO SP ON SP.COD_STATUS = SD.COD_STATUS
    LEFT JOIN TB_MEDIO_STATUS MS ON MS.COD_MEDIO_STATUS = SP.COD_MEDIO_STATUS
    left JOIN #TB_PROCESSO TT ON TT.COD_PROCESSO = TP.COD_PROCESSO
GROUP BY 
    TF.COD_FORNECEDOR,
    TF.NOM_FANTASIA,
    DM.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO,
    UA2.NOM_USUARIO,
    (SELECT COUNT(COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO) FROM TB_DEMANDA D INNER JOIN TB_PROCESSO P ON D.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO = P.NUM_CONTRATO WHERE D.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO = DM.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO)
ORDER BY TF.NOM_FANTASIA
```

Comment: Remove the line from your `GROUP BY` that has the nested query. You're already grouping on `DM.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO` which is the basis for the aggregate in the nested logic. Also, the column in your subquery that is inside the `COUNT` needs to have the table from which it is coming specified. Based upon the logic I think replacing this with a one should be sufficient since you're excluding `NULL`s with the join and not specificing Distinct which would be 1 anyways in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TF.COD_FORNECEDOR AS 'Cód. Fornec.',
    TF.NOM_FANTASIA AS 'Fornecedor',
    DM.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO AS 'CONTRATO',
    UA2.NOM_USUARIO AS 'NOM_USUARIO_COMPRADOR',
    sq.cnt AS 'NUM_ADITIVO',
    0 AS 'Qtd. Aditivo',
    SUM(DM.VAL_TOTAL_ORCADO) AS 'Valor Inicial',
    SUM(TP.VAL_CONTRATADO) AS 'Valor Final',
    ((SUM(TP.VAL_CONTRATADO) / SUM(DM.VAL_TOTAL_ORCADO)) -1) * 100 AS 'Var. %'
FROM TB_FORNECEDOR TF 
    LEFT JOIN TB_DEMANDA DM ON DM.COD_FORNECEDOR = TF.COD_FORNECEDOR
    LEFT JOIN TB_PROCESSO TP ON DM.COD_DEMANDA = TP.COD_DEMANDA
    LEFT JOIN TB_PROCESSO_FORNECEDOR PF ON PF.COD_PROCESSO = TP.COD_PROCESSO
    LEFT JOIN USUARIO UA ON UA.NUM_USUARIO = DM.NUM_USUARIO_COMPRADOR
    LEFT JOIN USUARIO UA2 ON UA2.NUM_USUARIO = DM.NUM_USUARIO_COMPRADOR
    LEFT JOIN TB_STATUS_DEMANDA_DATA SD ON SD.COD_DEMANDA = DM.COD_DEMANDA
    LEFT JOIN TB_BASELINE BA ON BA.COD_PROCESSO = TP.COD_PROCESSO
    LEFT JOIN TB_BASELINE_TAREFAS BT ON BT.COD_BASELINE = BA.COD_BASELINE AND BT.COD_PROCESSO = BA.COD_PROCESSO
    LEFT JOIN TB_STATUS_PROCESSO SP ON SP.COD_STATUS = SD.COD_STATUS
    LEFT JOIN TB_MEDIO_STATUS MS ON MS.COD_MEDIO_STATUS = SP.COD_MEDIO_STATUS
    LEFT JOIN #TB_PROCESSO TT ON TT.COD_PROCESSO = TP.COD_PROCESSO
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT D.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO, COUNT(COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO) AS cnt 
                FROM TB_DEMANDA D 
                        INNER JOIN TB_PROCESSO P ON D.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO = P.NUM_CONTRATO 
                GROUP BY D.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO
            ) sq ON sq.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO = DM.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO
GROUP BY 
    TF.COD_FORNECEDOR,
    TF.NOM_FANTASIA,
    DM.COD_CONTRATO_RELACIONADO,
    UA2.NOM_USUARIO,
    sq.cnt
ORDER BY TF.NOM_FANTASIA
```

I integrated the num_aditivo subquery in a LEFT JOIN.